# Classification problem (non separable data in 2D)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I have a data that consists of spectrum value at each wavelength (from 0 to 920). There are 5 different classes and spectrum value at specific wavelength decides to which class an input belongs to.

Consider this graph :[image]

As you can see, the data is not really separable, as at wavelength 200 classes have all the same spectrum level.

What can I do here? Is it possible to use soft margin SVM with kernel trick that may be adds 3rd dimension?

Comment: It looks looks linearly separable to me. For example, the example spectra can be perfectly classified  just by looking at the value at ~500nm

Comment: @user20160 Yes you were right, it gave me a 100% accuracy.